# Use Select Statement as a Parameter Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
 EXEC [dbo].[SP]
   @Param = ( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM TABLE )
```

Gives errors, so what's the next best thing or what am I doing wrong?

Without using `Declare` `Set` etc. etc.

Comment: Why without `DECLARE` `SET`, etc?  That's like asking how to making a paper plane without paper.

Comment: Umm, because that *is* the way you do it?

Comment: Hmm.. that's not intuitive. That's a 9gag material. SQL SERVER Y U NO ALLOW EXPRESSION ON PARAMETER?

Comment: Don't be mad because it doesn't work like its supposed to.  Or if you can't answer.

Comment: hahah I'm not mad, I just take jest on what's supposed to be working anyhow ;-)

Comment: I bet people from microsoft are probably downvoting this question.. lol

Comment: +1 this question, to restore some semblancy of normalcy to RDBMSes universe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set it before you run the stored proc?

```
SET @Para1 = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM TABLE)
EXEC [dbo].[SP] @Param = @Para1
```